# Python - Group by with multiple conditions on columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following example dataframe:

```
data = {'ref':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'checked':[True, True, True, False, True],
        'rag':['r', 'r', 'g', 'a', 'r'],
        'group':['high', 'low', 'high', 'medium', 'high']}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

I want to group on `group` and do some conditional counts where certain conditions are met so I get the following:

[image]

I can group by `group` and do `n` by the following:

```
df = dataframe.groupby(['group']).agg(
         n=('ref', 'count')
        ).reset_index()
```

But I am struggling to also count the number of times for each group that:

- checked = True
- rag = g
- rag = a
- rag = r

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

**edit:** changed True/False strings to Boolean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few challenges.

For instance, your True/False are strings, so you should either initialize them as booleans and use `sum` or convert to boolean during aggregation.

To count the rag, it's easier to use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and join it while you still have the groups as index.

```
df = (dataframe
      .groupby(['group'])
      .agg(**{'n': ('ref', 'count'),
              'checked=True': ('checked', lambda s: s.eq('True').sum()),
           })
      .join(pd.crosstab(dataframe['group'], dataframe['rag'])
              .add_prefix('rag=')
           )
      .reset_index()
     )
```

output:

```
    group  n  checked=True  rag=a  rag=g  rag=r
0    high  3             3      0      1      2
1     low  1             1      0      0      1
2  medium  1             0      1      0      0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `pivot_table` separately on your `checked` and `rag` columns

```py
n = df.groupby(['group']).agg(n=('ref', 'count'))

dfs = []
for column in ['checked', 'rag']:
    df_ = (df.pivot_table(index='group', columns=[column], values='ref',
                          aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
          .rename(columns=lambda col: f'{column}={col}')
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
    dfs.append(df_)
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).drop('checked=False', axis=1)
```

```
print(n.join(df))

        n  checked=True  rag=a  rag=g  rag=r
group
high    3             3      0      1      2
low     1             1      0      0      1
medium  1             0      1      0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your data example:

```
data = {'ref':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'checked':[True, True, True, False, True],
        'rag':['r', 'r', 'g', 'a', 'r'],
        'group':['high', 'low', 'high', 'medium', 'high']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

for `checked` column, you should enter value as `True/False` without in quotation. Otherwise, python will interpret `True'/'Fasle'` as `string`.

The idea here is two steps: (1) you use `iteration` with `groupby`. (2) then you `merge`/`concat` them into 1 table:

```
# Create empty table
table = pd.DataFrame()

# List of column you want to iterate:
col_iter = ['checked', 'rag']

# Iterate:
for col in col_iter:
    # Obtain unique values in each col used
    uni = df[col].unique()
    
    # Iterate for each unique value in col.
    # Set tem var
    # Concat tem to table
    for val in uni:
        tem = df.groupby('group').apply(lambda g: (g[col]==val).sum())
        table = pd.concat([table, tem], axis=1).rename(columns={0:f'{col}={val}'})
```